# Simple modal JSON Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, simplemodal

I will like to have have my content that is in a JSON file, populate my modal window  dynamically.
I want when everytime you click a corresponding the link or  maybe it can be a div with an ID on it....that specific content comes in the simple modal dialog window automatically .

JSON FILE

```
{
    "mycontent": [
        {
            "content": "content 1"
        }, {
            "entry": "content 2"
        }
        , {
            "entry": "content 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.getJSON('/json.json', function(data){

    // Load dialog on page load
    //$('#basic-modal-content').modal();

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href='#' class='basic'>content 1</a>
<a href='#' class='basic'>content 2</a>
<a href='#' class='basic'>content 3</a>
<div id="basic-modal-content" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I'm using: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Comment: What part are you stuck on? The JSON?

Comment: basically getting it to work, the Javascript part, not too sure how to get it the ID to be dynamic

Comment: Your JSON file contains an object with a field `mycontent` whose value is an array of objects, one of which has the field `content`, and the other two have the field `entry`. That is quite heterogenous, Where as your links look pretty homogenous. To Start, I would either restructure your JSON to match your links, or re-structure your links to match the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

look at this code:

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $.getJSON('/json.json', function(data){
        if( data != undefined && data.length > 0)
        {
            for( i=0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                $('#DIV-ID').append( data.i.content... .... .. you code here... );
            }
            $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```